# showing guild name & people requested the commands

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i'm trying to show the name of the guild & people who requested the commands.
i already tried `${message.guild.name}` & `$(message.author)` and it didn't work

heres my code

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .setColor('BLUE')
                            .setAuthor(' ${message.guild.name} Help Menu', message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
                            .setThumbnail(client.user.avatarURL())
                            .addField('All',"`ping`,`commands`,`commands`,`web`,`repost`,`help`")
                            .setFooter('Use % prefix in every command.More commands coming soon. Requested by $(message.author)', message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                            
                            .setTimestamp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use grave accents ``` (``) ``` and `${}` to make sure the variables are treated like variables.

**Wrong:**
.setAuthor('${message.guild.name}

**Right:**
.setAuthor(`${message.guild.name}

` and ' are very different, be mindful of that.

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('BLUE')
  .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Help Menu`, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
  .setThumbnail(client.user.avatarURL())                           
  .addField('All',"`ping`,`commands`,`commands`,`web`,`repost`,`help`")
  .setFooter(`Use % prefix in every command. More commands coming soon. Requested by 
  ${message.author}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
  .setTimestamp()
```

Answer (score 2):

`${}` is a template string. As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you need to use grave accents (`), not quotation marks.

You made another mistake at the `setFooter` function. You used round brackets instead of curly brackets.

```js
const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('BLUE')
    .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Help Menu`, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setThumbnail(client.user.avatarURL())
    .addField('All',"`ping`,`commands`,`commands`,`web`,`repost`,`help`")
    .setFooter(`Use % prefix in every command.More commands coming soon. Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    
    .setTimestamp()
```